# L.DomEvent.addListener() vs on(): why does one NOT work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, listener, addeventlistener

I created the following jquery script to cycle through each div in my HTML using a **for loop**.  In this for loop, I define the the div and add a listener to it:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    // Define listing
    var listing = $('div[data-rid="' + i + '"]');

    // Add listener to each listing div
    // See below...
}
```

I have tried two different ways to add a listener.  The first uses **L.DomEvent.addListener()** as such:

```
L.DomEvent.addListener(listing, 'mouseover', function(e) {
    // Do stuff to listing div
}
```

The second uses the action **mouseover()**:

```
listing.mouseover(function(e) {
    // Do stuff to listing div
}
```

The L.DomEvent.addListener approach **does not work**.  The mouseover approach works (i.e., it triggers for each div mouseover), but the "Do stuff to listing div" code only happens to the last listing div in the **for loop**.  For example, I might mouseover div #1, but it "does stuff" div #3.

**Does anyone have an idea how I might fix this issue?**

Thanks!

Jesse

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
L.DomEvent.addListener(listing[0], 'mouseover',     function(e) {
    // Do stuff to listing div
}
```

The case is, that the element jquery returns, is an array of the elements it found. listing[0] gets the first element in said array.